# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: carto, carto-js

Am new to cartodb and am  following this tutorial (http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/create_map_cartodbjs.html) on how to create a map.

When Implement the sql query, i get an error on the console saying "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)". I have included the screenshot of my browser displaying the error.

```
 var subLayerOptions = {
  sql: "SELECT * FROM my_cartodb_table_title WHERE city = 'CITY X' "
}


cartodb.createLayer(map, layerUrl/*, {no_cdn: true}*/)
.addTo(map)
.done( function(layer) {
  layer.getSubLayer(0).set(subLayerOptions);
  data_layer = layer.getSubLayer(0);
})
.error( function(err) {
  console.log("some error occurred: " + err);
});


      }
```

What could be the problem?

[image: Error log in the console]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request of your tiles is not being done correctly: check that the URLs you're showing include `undefined` as identifier.

This is probably caused by using CartoDB.js 3.11.23, which is a quite old version at the moment. The last version of 3.11 is 3.11.38 at this moment and it can be obtained with these URLs.

http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.11/themes/css/cartodb.css
http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.11/cartodb.js

3.11 for HTTPS:

https://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodb.js/v3/3.11/themes/css/cartodb.css
https://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodb.js/v3/3.11/cartodb.js

Right now, the last CartoDB.js release is version 3.15, whose URLs are the following ones:

http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/themes/css/cartodb.css

http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js

3.15 for HTTPS:

https://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/themes/css/cartodb.css

https://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js

If you're using the non-versioned URL for CartoDB.js (http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/cartodb.js
), you need to be aware that this non-versioned URLs are deprecated and should be no longer used, but you need to specify the version you want in the URL.

Comment: If this response solved your issue, could you mark it as answered so that other users could check it? :)

Comment: Hi, again. In my css code, just after my sql statement I added this line
`cartocss: "#table_title{marker-fill : #6d1948; marker-width: 5; marker-line-color: white; marker-line-width: 1;
      }"`
 and I get an errors in the console.
1. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`
2. `Uncaught ReferenceError: init is not defined`
I have declared the function init here   `<body onload="init()">`

What could be the problem. Many Thanks!

Comment: If it's a different question, could you open it as a new one? :)

Comment: Okay, Will do :-)